# ZCA whitening (MATLAB) - out of memory

Tags: matlab, neural-network, pca

Currently, I am doing texture classification by using Convolution Neural Networks. I am trying to implement the ZCA whitening to preprocess my images by using the Matlab code [here](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Implementing_PCA/Whitening).

Note that the size of my images are 512x512 with RGB JPEG format which cause out of memory in matrix multiplication. (However, I have my own reason that I cannot reduce the image size in my research)

Below is my code implementation, say, take [`lena.jpg`](http://bellard.org/bpg/lena30.jpg) (512x512) as example.

```
I = double(imread('lena.jpg')); % image size of 512x512
x = reshape(I, [], 3); % RGB vectors
avg = mean(x, 1);     % Compute the mean pixel intensity value separately for each channel. 
sigma = x * x' / size(x, 2); % <== I get error here
x = x - repmat(avg, size(x, 1), 1);
[U,S,V] = svd(sigma);
xZCAwhite = U * diag(1./sqrt(diag(S) + epsilon)) * U' * x;
```

Below is my `memory` status

```
Maximum possible array:        4338 MB (4.548e+09 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:        4338 MB (4.548e+09 bytes) *
Memory used by MATLAB:        1363 MB (1.429e+09 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):        8052 MB (8.443e+09 bytes)

*  Limited by System Memory (physical + swap file) available.
```

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your `reshape` is wrong...

When you read the image, it returns an 512*512*3 array `I`. When you reshape it with `reshape(I,[],3)`, it becomes an 262144*3 array `x`. Now `x*x'` would yield an 262144*262144 array, which is too large for your memory.

***EDIT:***

Apparently this is the correct procedure for ZCA whitening, but you should apply this on small patches of the image, in order to keep `size(x,1)*size(x,1)` tractable...

Comment: This is what I found from the [website](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Implementing_PCA/Whitening): "Here, we assume that `x` is a data structure that contains one training example per **column** (so, `x` is a `n`-by-`m` matrix)"
Therefore, my columns are R,G,B respectively and the row should be pixels for each channel.
Please correct me if my idea is wrong.

Comment: @EdwardSiew yes apparently your manipulation is correct in that context, but it is usually done on patches of the image ( like a 16*16 patch) which yields tractable `n=256`